# csharp method word first and last letter

Tags: c#

i have method, which have parameter "word" returns Word first and the last letter with string. between first and last letter there is three points. example when you write "stackoverflow" it returns it like that "s...w"

I have this code but i wont work.

```
namespace stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string word = "stackoverflow";
            string firsLast = FirsLast(word);
            Console.WriteLine(firsLast);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string FirsLast(string word)
        {
            string firsLast = "...";
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i += 2)
            {
                firsLast += word.ElementAt(i);
            }
            return firsLast;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So instead you're getting `...sakvrlw`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not

```
if (word.Length >= 2)
{
               return word[0] + "..." + word[word.Length - 1];
}
```

Comment: +1 - but I'd add a guard clause to ensure the word has a length of at least 2.

Comment: Be careful, check also word.Length (there could be special case when length is 0/1/2 chars)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think special case only when it is 0/1 but since he did not mention so I propose we just add to check minimum 2 chars present.

Comment: @IanNelson at least length 1 you mean: "w" = w...w

Answer (score 4):

```
if (word.Length >= 2)
{
    return word.First() + "..." + word.Last();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a loop to work this out. Rewrite your method as follows:

```
    private static string FirsLast(string word)
    {
        return word[0] + "..." + word[word.Length - 1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private static string FirsLast(string word)
    {

        string retVal = string.Format("{0}...{1}", word.Substring(0,1), word.Substring(word.Length - 1));

        return retVal;
    }
```